# C++ Dynamic Allocation, Is my use of new correct?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with dynamic allocation.In my code
am I initializing the dynamic array correctly?. 
When I try to write + operator member for my class String, it doesn't return what I want. Any guidance to the correct path would be great.

Ex.

```
String s1("One");
String s2("Two");
String s3 = s1+ s1;
cout <<s3;
//Output is OneTwo
cout <<s1;
//OUtput is OneTwo.
```

Also I don't understand why I can not add delete[] buf into my constructor.

```
class String{

public:

String (const char *s =""):buf(new char[strlen(s)]){
    buf = strdup(s);    
       };
String (const String &s):buf(new char[strlen(s.buf)]){
    buf = strdup(s.buf);
    delete []buf;
};

String operator =(const String &s){
    return buf =strdup(s.buf);
};

char & operator [] (int index){
    assert(inBounds(index));

    return buf[index];
};
int size()
{
    return strlen(buf);
};

String operator  + (const String s){
    delete []buf;

    char *temp = new char[strlen(buf)+strlen(s.buf)];

   ///NEed to ask about t*his acan get this operator tor work
    cout<< s.buf;
            return temp;
    };

String operator += (const String s){
    strcpy(buf + strlen(buf),s.buf);
    return buf;
};

void print(ostream & out){
    out << buf;
};

void read (istream & in){
    in >> buf;
};

~String(){
    //delete [] buf;
};

private:
    bool inBounds(int x){

    return x >= 0 && x < strlen(buf);
};

static int strlen(const char *s){
    int len =0;
    for(int i=0;s[i] != '\0';i++)
        len++;

    return len;
};

static char *strcpy(char *dest,const char *src){
    int i=0;

    for(;(dest[i] = src[i]); ++i);
    dest[i] = '\0';

    return dest;
};

static char *strdup(const char *s){
    char * buf;
    buf = new char[strlen(s)+1];

    int i=0;
    for(;s[i] != '\0';i++)
        buf[i] = s[i];

    buf[i] = '\0';
    return buf;
}  

char * buf;
};
```

Comment: The usage of `strdup` is wrong, as are many other things in your code.  You should spend time looking at properly implemented *simple*, home-made C++ string classes.  It would save you a lot of time in getting just the basics correct.  And please, do not use standard names for your class members -- it adds more confusion and could possibly conflict with the actual library function names in some contexts.

Comment: `strdup` returns a copy of the string allocated with `malloc`, and so must be cleared with `free` and not `delete[]`. This also means you leak the memory for `buf` in your constructor. You also do not check for self-assignment. There are many other problems.

Comment: @NeilKirk The OP seems to have used standard C-string function names for his implementation.  A very confusing piece of code...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok I didn't realise that, thanks.

Comment: There truly is too much wrong with this code to even comment.  A rewrite starting from scratch seems to be the only salvation.

Comment: Why did you comment out the destructor?

Comment: Because he was not yet aware of the fact that he's mixing new and malloc.  Thus he had crashes in the DTor.
Please do yourself a favour and restart from scratch NOT USING C-Utilities, that do their own memory allocations.

Comment: @OP:  Please look here: http://ideone.com/fxoZzh

Answer (score 1):

Your first constructor

```
String (const char *s ="") : buf(new char[strlen(s)]){
    buf = strdup(s);
}
```

first allocates a buffer that's one character too small, then it throws it away by pointing `buf`to the result of `strdup` – a memory leak.

You want

```
String (const char *s ="") : buf(new char[strlen(s) + 1]){
    strcpy(buf, s);
}
```

or

```
String (const char *s ="") : buf(strdup(s))
{
}
```

Your second constructor

```
String (const String &s) : buf(new char[strlen(s.buf)]){
    buf = strdup(s.buf);
    delete []buf;
};
```

has the same problem with a memory leak, and has the added complication that you immediately deallocate `buf`.

You want something like

```
String (const String& s) : buf(strdup(s.buf))
{
}
```

Your `+` deallocates `buf`, allocates an uninitialised (and too small) buffer, prints `buf`(which is undefined) and then returns a `String` made from the uninitialised buffer.

The addition operator should not modify `*this`; it should use `+=` and look like

```
String operator+ (const String& s) const 
{
    String result = *this;
    result += s;
    return result;
};
```

Which leaves `+=`, which needs to reallocate `buf` to be large enough to hold the result.
I'll leave it as an exercise.

And reimplementing standard library functions using the standard name is very confusing.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out @Molbdnilo. I'm still learning C++. Much appreciation.